# libvirt error when enabling hugepages for guest

Tags: kvm

I'm trying to set up a VM using libvirt and KVM through `virt-manager` (and `virsh` command line) with hugepages support and I get an error when enabling the option in the domain XML. Don't know where the problem is.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 upgraded to 14.10 with the following package versions:

- libvirt-bin 1.2.8-0ubuntu11
- qemu-kvm 2.1+dfsg-4ubuntu6

#### Specifics

I have configured hugepages following this [guide](https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages). Here is some info about current configuration:

```
$ hugeadm --explain
Total System Memory: 15808 MB

Mount Point          Options
/dev/hugepages       rw,relatime,mode=1770,gid=126

Huge page pools:
      Size  Minimum  Current  Maximum  Default
   2097152     2176     2176     2176        *

Huge page sizes with configured pools:
2097152

$ getent group kvm
kvm:x:126:chaicko

$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
AnonHugePages:    591872 kB
HugePages_Total:    2176
HugePages_Free:     2176
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

This is the domain XML:

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>win8</name>
  <uuid>b85bbb9a-745f-4293-a990-1e1726240ef0</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <memoryBacking>
    <hugepages/>
  </memoryBacking>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-utopic'>hvm</type>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Haswell</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
      <source dev='/dev/vmvg/win8'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <boot order='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/chaicko/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1-81.iso'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/chaicko/Downloads/WINDOWS_8.1_Pro_X64/Windows_8.1_Pro_X64.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:48:ca:09'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'/>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0b' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-drive'/>
    <qemu:arg value='if=pflash,readonly,format=raw,file=/usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

#### Questions

If I remove the `<memoryBacking>` option then it works but if not it fails with the the following error:

```
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor:
```

Also I've uncommented the following line in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`:

```
hugetlbfs_mount = "/dev/hugepages"
```

Running qemu through the shell instructing to use the hugepages do actually work (`-mem-path /dev/hugepages`).

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, in order to use hugepages with `libvirt` in *Ubuntu*, you just have to set `KVM_HUGEPAGES=1` in the file `/etc/default/qemu-kvm` and restart.

This is related with this [bugfix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1250216).

Answer (score 4):

Per the libvirt documentation, in this section titled: [Memory Backing](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsMemoryBacking).

> The optional memoryBacking element may contain several elements that influence how virtual memory pages are backed by host pages.
>
> ***hugepages***
>
> This tells the hypervisor that the guest should have its memory
>   allocated using hugepages instead of the normal native page size.
>   Since 1.2.5 it's possible to set hugepages more specifically per numa
>   node. The page element is introduced. It has one compulsory attribute
>   size which specifies which hugepages should be used (especially useful
>   on systems supporting hugepages of different sizes). The default unit
>   for the size attribute is kilobytes (multiplier of 1024). If you want
>   to use different unit, use optional unit attribute. For systems with
>   NUMA, the optional nodeset attribute may come handy as it ties given
>   guest's NUMA nodes to certain hugepage sizes. From the example
>   snippet, one gigabyte hugepages are used for every NUMA node except
>   node number four. For the correct syntax see [this](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsMemoryTuning).
>
> ***nosharepages***
>
> Instructs hypervisor to disable shared pages (memory merge, KSM) for
>   this domain. Since 1.0.6
>
> ***locked***
>
> When set and supported by the hypervisor, memory pages belonging to
>   the domain will be locked in host's memory and the host will not be
>   allowed to swap them out. For QEMU/KVM this requires hard_limit [memory
>   tuning](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsMemoryTuning) element to be used and set to the maximum memory configured for
>   the domain plus any memory consumed by the QEMU process itself. Since
>   1.0.6

#### Example

```
<domain>
  ...
  <memoryBacking>
    <hugepages>
      <page size="1" unit="G" nodeset="0-3,5"/>
      <page size="2" unit="M" nodeset="4"/>
    </hugepages>
    <nosharepages/>
    <locked/>
  </memoryBacking>
  ...
</domain>
```

Since you do not say, I'm assuming you want to allocate all the memory to this particular guest. If so you could probably try omitting this section completely.

#### Alternative directions

I found these RHEL 5 & 6 steps in this article titled: [How do I set up KVM guests to use HugePages?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/36741) that show how to set this up as follows:

*excerpt*

> #### Mount the HugeTLB filesystem on the host
>
> You may use any mountpoint desired, here we have created /hugepages
>
> ```
>   mkdir -p /hugepages
>   mount -t hugetlbfs hugetlbfs /hugepages
> ```
>
> This is also possible via an entry in `/etc/fstab`, for example
>
> ```
>   hugetlbfs    /hugepages    hugetlbfs    defaults    0 0
> ```
>
> #### Increase the memory lock limit on the host
>
> Alter the following values in `/etc/security/limits.conf` depending on
>   your required memory usage
>
> ```
>   # Lock max 8Gb
>   soft memlock 8388608
>   hard memlock 8388608
> ```
>
> #### Reserve HugePages and give the KVM group access to them
>
> Alter to following lines in `/etc/sysctl.conf` depending on your required 
>   memory usage
>
> ```
>   vm.nr_hugepages = 4096
>   vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 36
> ```
>
> #### Add HugePage backing to the KVM guest definition
>
> Add the following to the guest config of an existing KVM guest. This
>   can be done with `virsh edit <guestname>` or `virsh define
>   <guest.xml>`
>
> ```
>   <memoryBacking>
>       <hugepages/>
>   </memoryBacking>
> ```
>
> #### Restart the host
>
> This is required to re-allocate contigous memory to HugePages
>
> #### Start a guest
>
> Confirm the guest has HugePage backing Check the `qemu-kvm` process
>   associated with that guest for the presence of -`mem-path` in the run
>   command
>
> ```
>   ps -ef | grep qemu
>
>   root      4182     1  1 17:35 ?        00:00:42 /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -S -M rhel5.4.0 -m 1024 -mem-prealloc
> -mem-path /hugepages/libvirt/qemu -smp 1 -name vm1 -uuid 3f1f3a98-89f8-19ac-b5b5-bf496e2ed9be -no-kvm-pit-reinjection
> -monitor pty -pidfile /var/run/libvirt/qemu//vm1.pid -boot c -drive file=/vmimages/vm1,if=ide,index=0,boot=on,cache=none
> -drive file=,if=ide,media=cdrom,index=2 -net nic,macaddr=54:52:00:00:00:01,vlan=0 -net tap,fd=15,script=,vlan=0,ifname=vnet0
> -serial pty -parallel none -usb -vnc 127.0.0.1:0 -k en-us
> ```
>
> #### Confirm HugePage use on the system
>
> Here we can see HugePages are being allocated at startup, as well as
>   used/reserved for the guests
>
> ```
>   cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
>
>   HugePages_Total:    4096
>   HugePages_Free:      873
>   HugePages_Rsvd:      761
>   Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
> ```
>
> #### Root Cause
>
> The default method of allocating memory for KVM guests is to use
>   regular 4k pages. This can result in
>
> - large page tables which occupy unnecessary and inefficient amounts of memory
> - increased memory fragmentation which can slow down some kernel-based actions which require contigous memory (eg: disk writes, network
>     access)
> - increasing page faults which can slow down all applications
> - risking swapping components of virtual guests out to disk which would cause a large performance hit
>
> Using HugePages, page table sizes are dramatically reduced, contigous
>   areas of memory are mapped, and HugePages cannot be swapped by design.
>
> **Note:** These steps are not necessary with KVM on RHEL6, which uses Transparent HugePages to dynamically map contigous 2Mb areas of memory
>   but also allows that memory to be broken up into 4k pages to be merged
>   with KSM or swapped when the system is under memory pressure.
>
> The above steps can be applied to RHEL6 if HugePages are desired over
>   Transparent HugePages.

Comment: it is related with AppArmor in ubuntu, specifically with this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1250216)

Answer (score 1):

> qemu-system-x86_64: unable to map backing store for guest RAM: Cannot
>   allocate memory

Certify guest memory does not exceed the amount allocated to Hugepages.